# how to make String in array of string equals in length by adding space?

Tags: java

i'm working on a project and i want to display table of drug doses, i have problem for string space alignment and i try to fix it as the following:

```
   for ( int drug = 0; drug < doses.length; drug++ ) 
    { 
    str+=opDrugs[drug]; 
    int x=getLongestString().length();  
    int y=getShortestString().length();
    while (y<x)
    {str+=" ";
        y++;}
```

i want the first column equals in length, but the output still as the following:

```
                    Time1   Time2   Time3   Total
    O2                  99      96      70        265.0
    N2O                  68      87      90        245.0
    gas                  94      100      90        284.0
    musle relaxent                  100      81      82        263.0
    narcotic                  83      65      85        233.0
    fluid                  78      87      65        230.0
    atropine                   85      75      83        243.0
    neostagmine                  91      94      100        285.0
```

Comment: You're going at it the wrong way. You want to _format_ your input. Look at `System.out.printf` and `Formatter`.

Comment: I like using this [cheat sheet](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Fall15/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf) when working with `printf`.

Comment: @Tunaki i dont want use System.out.printf , are there a method to format individual string as we use in printf ??

Comment: Instead of adding spaces, replace them by one \t for each token, skipping the while loop on longest/shortest lengths

Answer (score 0):

The fastest not very Trustable way: use `\t` for the tab character.

The trustable way: use `System.out.printf()`

```
public static void main(){
String str1
int i1,i2;
float num4;

str1= "O2";
i1=99;
i2=96;      
num4=265.0;
System.out.printf("%10s\t%2d\t%2d\t%.2f\n",str1,i1,i2,num4);
}
```

As you can see you can make all the strings use the same space, and with `%.2f` you can control how many decimals are shown. The `\n` creates a new line in the output.

If you only want the string without printing it you can use

```
String result = String.format("%10s\t%2d\t%2d\t%.2f\n",str1,i1,i2,num4);
```

To avoid errors with the strings you should prefereably calculathe the longest one in another method and sent it as parameter.

```
int longest=findLongestString(String[] opDrugs);
for ( int drug = 0; drug < doses.length; drug++ ) 
{
 String result = String.format("%"+longest+"s\t%2d\t%2d\t%.2f\n",opDrugs[drug],i1,i2,num4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines:

1. work out the maximum size of the first column.  Assuming your function getLongestString().length(); does this, the code would be:

str += opDrugs[drug];

int column1_width = getLongestString().length();

2. Assuming you want at least one space, add one to that

columnn1_width +=1;

3. Print the number of spaces depending on the current string length:

`int num_spaces = column1_width - opDrugs[drug].length;
    for ( int space_num = 0;space_num < num_spaces; space_num++ )
    {
        str += " ";
    }`